# native-package-manager and sbt-git plugins not found on maven repo

Tags: sbt-native-packager, sbt-git

I believe that the two plugins are not available anymore on maven central repository. I am not able to add them to the project. Everytime I get the error about unknown artifact. This has stopped working recently. Any idea if about how can I get these two plugins??

Answer (score 0):

Previously most SBT plugins were hosted on bintray which has been taken offline. sbt-native-packager moved to maven central since 1.9.1 and the organization in the maven coordinates had to change for that reason.

Please the the current readme for the up to date coordinates

Cheers,
Muki